# Php form for registered users in joomla

Tags: php, joomla

I am using joomla cms for my website, I need to add a php form for example to edit their profile details of registered users. I have created a separate php form to do so. I could use the wrapper module to display this form for registered users. But when i copy the link for ex, http://localhost/joomla/edit-your-profile.php , public user can still view and use that form. So I need to check whether user logged in or not using session/$my variable details. Is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

### SEE [Joomla Login Session Tutorial](http://itjungles.com/other/joomla-login-session)

(via [Custom Sessions with Joomla](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1066676/custom-sessions-with-joomla) which should also be helpul.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use a [form builder](http://phpforms.net/tutorial/html-basics/form-builder.html). You will only need to create a PHP form by means of an intuitive interface and generate a code that can be easily copied and pasted to any web page.